# Centralize configuration using Consul in Micronaut

Tags: java, consul, micronaut

I'm switching from Spring Boot to Micronauts micro-service, in Spring Framework we have centralized configuration using Spring Cloud Consul. I am looking for same feature with Micronaut application.

I have different micro-services which have some common configuration, as well as some different configuration, I want to make common in one place and non-common in another place.

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: feteBirdProduct
  server:
    port: 8083
kafka.bootstrap.servers: localhost:9092
consul:
  client:
    registration:
      enabled: true
      check:
        http: true
    defaultZone: "${CONSUL_HOST:localhost}:${CONSUL_PORT:8500}"
```

In the above code, I have a `kafka.bootstrap.servers` which will be common for all the micro-services, however, other such as name and port will be for particular micro-services. How can I achieve this